# Grails cascade validation for domain objects not mapped to a table

Tags: validation, grails, cascade

Please can you help me with the problem below:

I have 2 domain classes(Parent, Child) which I do not want to be mapped to a table, so I put `mapWith=none`. However, when I do `parent.validate()` I want the validation to be cascaded to the child. How can I enable cascade validation for domain objects which are not mapped to a table?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you can by design.

You could optionally add a customValidation() method on the parent object to initiate a check which is looping over the children and invoking their validate() methods. Any errors on the children could then be added to the errors object of the parent object.

```
boolean cascadedValidation() {
    this.validate();

    children.each {
        if (!it.validate()) {
           it.errors.allErrors.each { err ->
               // Bind somewhere on parent object
           }
        }
    }

    return this.hasErrors();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your solution! I was thinking to do something similar  too, but I am not very happy as it's more a bandaid.... :( I saw in GormValidationApi an if statement which tests if the current validator is instance of CascadeValidator...I'm trying to find a way to inject an instance of CascadeValidator to that validate Gorm method so that it will force to cascade.

Comment: there must be an workaround or a solution for this, cannot believe you can't cascade validation unless you map the domain to a table!

Comment: Maybe this post is of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040596/grails-validation-of-a-list-objects