# Using Custom Validator on List

Tags: grails, customvalidator

I have a Command Object as follows :

```
class TestCreationCommand {

    String title    
    List testItems = [].withLazyDefault {new VocabQuestion()}

    static constraints = {
        title(blank:false,maxLength:150)

        testItems( validator: { ti ->
            ti.each {it.validate()}
        } )
    }
}
```

Test Items is a list of VocabQuestion objects. VocabQuestion is as follows :

```
class VocabQuestion {

    static constraints = {
        question(blank:false,maxLength:150)
        answer(blank:false,maxLength:40)
    }

    static belongsTo = [vocabularyTest: VocabularyTest]

    String question
    String answer

}
```

I'm attempting to validate the constraints on the VocabQuestion using a custom vaildator ( in the constraints of the Command class above ), but I keep getting the following error message.

```
Return value from validation closure [validator] of property [testItems] of class [class vocabularytest.TestCreationCommand] is returning a list but the first element must be a string containing the error message code
```

I have had *many* different attempts at this .....

I am not sure what the message is telling me  or how to go about debugging what the return value from the closure is.

Can anyone provide me any pointers?

Comment: Did you attempt returning a Boolean or an error message key? See here a link that still applies http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Constraints/validator.html

Comment: Tried both of those - no luck..... I'm on the verge of giving up with Grails. Unless you stick exactly to a fairly simple CRUD scheme like it generates out of the box, then I find that I'm spending most oif my time fighting the framework, rather than it helping me to be productive

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning what Grails understands. You can't expect to just return anything and have Grails know what to do with it. Return a boolean or an error string.

```
static constraints = {
        title(blank:false,maxLength:150)

        testItems( validator: { ti ->
            Boolean errorExists = false
            ti.each {
               if (!it.validate()) {
                 errorExists = true
               }
            }
            errorExists
        })
    }
```

Comment: +1. I would rather use a `for` loop and `break` out if there is any error, with the flag set to `true`. or return the flag immediately if it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040596/grails-validation-of-a-list-objects) It might be the format of the validator you need.

The .every will return a boolean.